# Formatting a date in Russian in Swift uppercase first letter

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I change my date format to get it in russian. But, result is lowercased (январь). How to make it's first letter uppercased (Январь)?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(stringDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use capitalized in string date.

You can get first letter uppercased

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "RU-ru")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
        let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date()).capitalized
        print(stringDate)
```