# How to get date string with capitalized first letter?

Tags: ios, swift, date-format

I am trying to localize string.

In English I am getting a date string like "Friday, Jun 26" but in Spanish it's like "jueves, jun 25".

The first letter is small but I am trying to get a capitalized first letter just like English.

Below is my code.

```
let longDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
longDateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d"
longDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")
```

Is there any way to get date with first letter capitalized?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/59434614

Comment: Also possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26306326

Comment: Also, for proper localization consider using [.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla) instead of direct `dateFormat` assignment.

Comment: Just for context (though you might already know this), weekdays aren't capitalized in Spanish like they are in English

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Spanish does not capitalize the names of months and days of the week like we do in English. Thus the format you are getting is correct for Spanish, and you should stop trying to change it. (in essence, this is an x/y problem.)

See this link: [https://www.spanishdict.com/answers/181002/do-months-need-to-be-capitalized-in-spanish#:~:text=Spanish%20does%20NOT%20capitalize%3A&text=%3F-,Calendar%3A%20Names%20of%20the%20days%20of%20the,and%20months%20of%20the%20year.&text=%3F-,Nationality%3A%20Although%20names%20of%20countries%20and%20cities%20are%20capitalized%2C%20words,derived%20from%20them%20are%20not](https://www.spanishdict.com/answers/181002/do-months-need-to-be-capitalized-in-spanish#:%7E:text=Spanish%20does%20NOT%20capitalize%3A&text=%3F-,Calendar%3A%20Names%20of%20the%20days%20of%20the,and%20months%20of%20the%20year.&text=%3F-,Nationality%3A%20Although%20names%20of%20countries%20and%20cities%20are%20capitalized%2C%20words,derived%20from%20them%20are%20not).

If you want to do something different than the correct localization for Spanish you will need to take the output from the Spanish localization and manipulate it. You could simply use `longDateFormatter.string(from: date).capitalized`, which would capitalize every word in the resulting date string.

```
let longDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
longDateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d"
longDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")

let output = longDateFormatter.string(from: Date()).capitalized
print(output)
```

Yields

> Viernes, Jun 26

But again, that is the **WRONG** way to display dates in Spanish. It is every bit as wrong as displaying "friday, june 26" in English.

### Edit on 26 October 2023:

Note that as mentioned by @user28434'mstep, for localized date conversions, it's better to set the formatter's format string using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`. With that change, the code above (without forcing the output to be capitalized) would look like this:

```
let longDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
longDateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE, MMM d")
longDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")
    
let output = longDateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(output)
```

(In this particular case it seems that `longDateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE, MMM d")` and `longDateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d"` yield the same results, but using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` for localizable formatters is still best practice.)